# Trending #tags webpart not working - SP 2013

Tags: web-part, social, hashtags

We are having a problem with our "Trending #tags" webpart that is not displaying any data. It resides on the MySite host default page, (default.aspx).

From my understanding #tags which are mentioned on the newsfeed should appear within this webpart? Thus I have created multiple conversations with different #tags but no success with the webpart.

It just displays:
"Tagging's been quiet lately. No trending tags right now."

Am I missing a step maybe? I have looked around but found nothing.

Thanks in advance...

EDIT: Would Search crawls have anything to do with this?

Comment: Merging this with a newer very similar question - hope that may get this answered.

Comment: also fighting with this ...tried everything..added the default content account to the metadata service etc. etc.... still not working is this a MS bug?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Messing with the default search configuration was a bad idea, re-added the default content sources and the webpart populated. Re-deploying Search Service application could be easier and cleaner.

Comment: Currently having this issue. What a terrible answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate to Search Service Application > Content Sources and ensure that 'Local SharePoint Sites' content source has been crawled before.  This should resolve the problem.

http://usesharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/taggings-been-quite-lately.html